# How to make capturePage work when the window is not visible?

Tags: electron

I'm trying to use capturePage on a window in Electron and when the window is not visible because it's obscure entirely by other windows, it dumps an empty PNG.

I tried passing these options individually when creating the window but they made not difference:

```
 useContentSize: true,
 enableLargerThanScreen: true
 webPreferences: {
   offscreen: true
   webgl: false
 }
```

Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 7):

The following code works for hidden, offscreen and visible browser windows as well even when they're covered by other windows

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const fs = require('fs')

app.on('ready', () => {
  let win = new BrowserWindow({
    show: false // or true
  })
  win.webContents.on('did-stop-loading', () => {
    win.capturePage((image) => {
      fs.writeFile('test.png', image.toPNG(), (err) => {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log('It\'s saved!')
        app.quit()
      })
    })
  })
  win.loadURL('http://github.com')
})
```

If you receive empty PNG with this code it indicates that browser window **is not ready for capture yet**. It might be the situation in your case, too!

---

*`capturePage` seems to be missing some pieces of the webview in the created image in older electron versions sometimes (experienced in 1.8.4)*

Comment: Could you explain this seemingly unnecessary "setTimeout" inside page-title-updated callback?

Comment: @neo At the time of writing (electron 1.8.4) I experienced some issues with this code: The saved image was sometimes missing details (texts, images not rendered), thus I used this dirty timeout workaround. Now, I've just realized that 1.) electron 4.0 doesn't have this issue anymore 2.) There are events better fit for completely loaded page 3.) it wasn't a proper workaround anyway. I've edited the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

First of all **@pergy** answer works, thanks him for that.

I want to share some changes (**electron@11.2.3**) and some hacks:

- If you want to use this method not inside root `BrowserWindow`, but somewhere inside your application you will be unable to use `new BrowserWindow()`, instead you should add `enableRemoteModule: true` in root BrowserWindow, and use `new remote.BrowserWindow()` where you want inside your application;
- I prefer to use `dom-ready` event not `did-stop-loading`, on this moment the page have been loaded but annoying widgets are not;
- I'm not sure if `win.capturePage` will work, it's recommended to use `win.webContents.capturePage()`